# convert and filter datetime with mysql

Tags: date, datetime, mysqli, date-format

Iam struggling to get all dates from now (all dates from today or the future).

Unfortunately my dates are in this format: '%d%m%Y %H:i' (08.06.2013 12:00)

I tried a couple of things, the last was:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(enddate,1,9),'%Y%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d')
```

I thought this would convert into: (when date = 27.08.2013)

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE 20130827 >= 20130608
```

But its now working... I get too much results :-/

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: You have to change your date format to a proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `STR_TO_DATE` ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)).

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(enddate, '%Y.%m.%d') >= CURDATE();
```

`STR_TO_DATE` parses the string according to given format (`'%Y.%m.%d'` in your case) and returns a date string that can be used with MySQL. Once converted, you can freely compare it against other date values or functions like `CURDATE`. You should read the documentation for more details.

In the longer run, you will be better off using actual `DATE` and `DATETIME` columns.